# join generator of bytes - specified object join not found

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to join the stdout of a subprocess. Popen which is a bytes list. when I'm trying to do it directly from the shell everything seems to be fine, but when I execute it from a script I get the following error:

```
*** The specified object "''.join(out)" is not a function or was not
found along sys.path.
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
popen = subprocess.Popen('..some unix command..', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out = (line for line in popen.stdout)

b''.join(out)
```

Any ideas why this won't work from inside the script itself or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: couldn't replicate the error , on what line do you get the error?

Comment: Ohhhhh hold on, it's only happening when I'm not pushing the b''.join to a variable

BYW, this is the line I get the error from only on script

Comment: That just makes it stranger still